# Error with UINavigationController Animations when Returning from A Sub-view with No Status Bar (iOS 8)

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, statusbar

I am trying to create an ios 7 targetted application that has a UINavigationController that navigates to a sub-view with no status bar.

The problem is that, in iOS 8, when the navigation controller pops back to a view with a status bar then the navigation bar of the view being popped to animates off the screen in conjunction with the subview with no status bar.

I have not programmed any animations and am relying solely on iOS7 to do the transitions for me.

Here is the simplest code that I can show that exhibits the issue

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RootView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    RootView *rootView = [[RootView alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootView];
    self.window.rootViewController=navController;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

**RootView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootView : UIViewController

@end
```

**RootView.m**

```
#import "RootView.h"
#import "SubView.h"

@implementation RootView

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Root View";
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:@"Press" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(showSubView)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)showSubView {
    SubView *subView = [[SubView alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:subView animated:YES];
}

@end
```

**SubView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SubView : UIViewController

@end
```

**SubView.m**

```
#import "SubView.h"

@implementation SubView

-(BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Thats all the code you need to show the behaviour.

1. Run the application
2. You will see a UINavigationController with the RootView and the root view
3. You can see the navigation item title "Root View"
4. Press the button with "Press" on it
5. The SubView is pushed onto the navigation controller stack. The status bar goes away as required and expected.
6. Click the 'Root View' left button to pop the sub view off of the stack and return to the root view
7. Expected: The navigation controller should show a transition to the root view and the title should be displayed properly.
8. Actual: The 'Root View' is displayed, but the title ("Root View") is shown immediately and gets animated off of the screen along with the sub view.

Is this a bug? It is certainly unexpected behaviour.

If I return NO from prefersStatusBarHidden in the sub-view then everything behaves exactly as I would expect it to. If I run this on an iOS7 device then everything works as expected.

This is the first large iOS application that I have built and I have no idea how to deal with this. I have read many posts on animation for the navigation controller, but I am not dealing with any animations. I am merely hiding the status bar on the sub view in the iOS 7 recommended way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Conrad

Comment: It is possible that this is only an iOS 8 issue. I have an iPod touch with iOS 8 on it and it exhibits this behaviour. My colleague has an iPhone with iOS 7 on it and the code of our application seems to work correctly on it. He has not yet tested the simple code I posted above.

Comment: This is indeed only an iOS 8 issue, and I have updated the question accordingly.